# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'src/protos/user.proto'?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, enoent, esmodules

I'm creating a node.js gRPC service. I'm using the photo buff as an npm package in this service. so the proto buff package is structured as below.

[image]

and I have published this package to the GitHub npm package registry. then I used it in my user-management service as an npm package. But when I use the proto object from this library I'm receiving the following error,

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'src/protos/user.proto'
```

and this is how I create a proto object

```js
import grpc from "grpc";
import protoLoader from "@grpc/proto-loader";

var USER_PROTO_PATH = "./src/protos/user.proto";
/**
 * Package definition
 */
const userPackageDef = protoLoader.loadSync(USER_PROTO_PATH, {});
/**
 * gRPC Objects
 */
const grpcUserObject = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(userPackageDef);
/**
 * Packages
 */
export const userPackage = grpcUserObject.userPackage;
```

and this is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "@example/protobuff",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "description": "gRPC protocol buffer of app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/@example"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://github.com/example/protobuff.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "protobuff"
  ],
  "author": "Test user",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/example/protobuff/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/example/protobuff#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "grpc": "^1.24.11"
  }
}
```

what should I do to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by setting the proto file path as below.

```
var USER_PROTO_PATH = "./node_modules/@example/protobuff/src/protos/user.proto"
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you had to move your file into the node_module folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the path, you might want to make it more dynamic, especially if the file structure can vary between projects. You can use the __dirname variable to get the absolute path of the current module and then append the relative path to your protobuf file.

```
const path = require('path');

const USER_PROTO_PATH = path.join(__dirname, 'src/protos/user.proto');
```

Consider organising your protobuf files in a separate 'protos' directory within your npm package. Then, adjust the path accordingly:

```
const USER_PROTO_PATH = path.join(__dirname, 'protos/user.proto');
```

This can help maintain a cleaner project structure.